# Transfer testing server files to live server and avoid errors

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

I am aware that transferring files from local/testing servers to a live site server is a pretty cut-and-dry process. However, I have had several issues with the one site that I am working on for a client.

The site is using a mysql database for much of the information and images supplied since it is a retail-based business with thousands of patterns/swatches to choose from. All of my files transferred perfectly to testing and work correctly. However, when I in-turn push the files live, I receive the following error messages:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /home/warner_walls/warnerwalls.com/advsearch.php on line 133
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/warner_walls/warnerwalls.com/advsearch.php on line 133
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/warner_walls/warnerwalls.com/advsearch.php on line 134
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /home/warner_walls/warnerwalls.com/advsearch.php on line 148
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/warner_walls/warnerwalls.com/advsearch.php on line 148
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/warner_walls/warnerwalls.com/advsearch.php on line 241

Please note that the database connection is the same for both the test server and live server; which is why I cannot figure out why it works on one and not the other. I have used the program, TextWrangler to compare all php pages in question to find differences in the code that may be causing the error and all pages are marked to be identical.

The images that are being requested in the search, when the error messages appear, are displayed correctly, it is just the error statements are overlapping the last line of swatches and stacked under from there.

What should I be looking for to help correct this?

Comment: Are the correct folder permissions set?

Comment: Could you show us the code that is causing this? Are you trying to connect remotely even though you are on the same machine?

Comment: @DaveChen all settings are correct and folders are set to 755.

Comment: Lines in question are:                                                                 (line 133)  $tot=mysql_query($query);
(line 134)  $total_pages = mysql_num_rows($tot);                      (line 148)  $results = mysql_query($query);                           (line 241)  while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){

Answer (score 0):

The first error message is quite clear:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: **Can't connect** to local
>   MySQL server **through socket** '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in
>   /home/warner_walls/warnerwalls.com/advsearch.php on line 133

Of course, the *local* MySQL server is running?

It is configured to listen for local connection on the unix socket? (check in `/etc/my.cnf` for the line `socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`)

---

If you have copied *all* the DB files from the live server to your test platform, I assume you have copied the mysql DB files too (those that store user tables, permissions and so on).

That would be confirmed when you say "that the database connection is the same for both the test server and live server".

If that analysis is not *totally completely* stupid, my *guess* would be the DB is configured to [grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) permissions to `user@ip_address` or `user@%` -- but not to `user@localhost`.